# Modify file move/delete queue on NTFS?

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-recovery

The problem occurs when opened file is moved. It appears in new location, and file in old location (if it is on another disk) gives [0xC0000056 / STATUS_DELETE_PENDING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx).

It looks different when the file is deleted or renamed. It disappears from directory, though the application that locked it still can read file contents from its original location.

Is there a way to undo move/delete operation in such cases? These are rare but existent situations that have to be treated with undelete tools otherwise.

Notice that it is not the same as the queue in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\FileRenameOperations`.